# Decimating Minecraft Leaves to Reduce Poly Count?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have a huge group of leaves from a Minecraft map that I am trying to reduce the polygon count on for LOD use later in Unity.  The tris on all leaves combined is 10.5 million.  What would be the best way to do this?

It would be ideal if I could just remove the insides of the blocks representing the leaves, as there is a lot of empty space in there that nobody playing will see.